# Continuous Delivery - Acceptance test stored alongside artifacts?

Tags: continuous-integration, acceptance-testing, continuous-deployment

I'm looking into migrating towards a CD pipeline with compile stage and acceptance stages.

Currently I have acceptance tests in my repository, living alongside my service code.

After the compile stage is successful and some form of artifact has been pushed to my repository, I'm trying to figure out the best strategy for the next stage.

I really want to keep my acceptance tests in the same repository as my service code, I want to maintain a quick feedback loop when writing a new test and implementing the solution.

Is it bad practice to store the acceptance test code (C# dll(s)) alongside the build artifacts, retrieve and execute them against the service code I have just deployed??

Answer (score 0):

@adm, it is not entirely a bad or a good practice. The storage of acceptance test is usually decided by the size of your repository. If you have a sizeable repository , it might be a good idea to break it down. Otherwise, both test resources and output can be stored in a repository and it is definitely not bad

One disadvantage however is that , if you have  lockdown/freeze mechanisms in your codebase , you might not be able to update the test cases during the lockdown/freeze period.